# SVG currentScale not working

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I'm trying to scale an SVG, and elsewhere it suggests currentScale should work.

If I try the following, the value stays the same, as though its read only ?

```
<svg id="mysvg"><rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/></svg> 

var svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
console.log( svg.currentScale );
svg.currentScale = 10;
console.dir( svg.currentScale );
```

The scale remains at 1. I can't figure if I'm missing something obvious, or if there's a bug there.

This is in Chrome 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit)
Edit..it looks like it has an effect in Firefox.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4vckb2g/1/)

Comment: currentScale only applies to SVG pages I think not to SVG embedded within an HTML page. I think that's a Chrome bug, perhaps you should report it.

Comment: This is a bug in Blink, see http://crbug.com/174568.

Answer (score -2):

First of All Use IE browsers.

and also svg.setAttribute("currentScale", 10);

Comment: I think this not provide an answer to the question as "using IE" is not the solution

Comment: currentScale property correctly supported only under IE.
For other browser use transform="scale(2)"